# How do I implement a key to be both PK and FK?

Tags: sql

I'm very new to SQL and just practicing for my SQL exam by going through past papers, however, I'm stuck on how to implement the staffID & projNo in the allocation table to be both primary and foreign keys. I've tried to use solutions online but none work.

Here is the relational schema (**PK**, *FK*)

```
staff( **staffID**, firstname, lastName, gender, dob, jobTitle)

project ( **projNo**, projName, description )

allocation ( ***staffID***, ***projNo***, hours )
```

Here is my SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE staff (
  staffID CHAR (4) PRIMARY KEY,
  firstName VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
  lastName VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
  gender CHAR (1) CHECK (gender IN ('M','F'))
  dob DATE NOT NULL,
  jobTitle VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
  );


CREATE TABLE project (
  projNo CHAR (4) PRIMARY KEY,
  projName VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
  description VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
  );


CREATE TABLE allocation (
  staffID CHAR (4) 
  projNo CHAR (4) 
  hours int (2)
  );
```

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: Show us your attempt with both fk and pk as well!

Comment: Unrelated, but: `char` is almost always the wrong choice (for anything longer than 1 character). `varchar` is never worse but almost always better.

Answer (score 0):

Making the two column to have Primary Key Constraint Use;

Alter table table_name Add MyPrimaryConstraint Primary Key(column(s));

Answer (score 0):

There's really not much to it:

```
CREATE TABLE allocation (
  staffID CHAR (4)
    CONSTRAINT ALLOCATION_FK1
      REFERENCES STAFF(STAFFID)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
  projNo CHAR (4) 
    CONSTRAINT ALLOCATION_FK2
      REFERENCES PROJECT(PROJNO)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
  hours int (2),
  CONSTRAINT PK_ALLOCATION
    PRIMARY KEY (STAFFID, PROJNO)
      USING INDEX
  );

CREATE INDEX ALLOCATION_1
  ON ALLOCATION (STAFFID);

CREATE INDEX ALLOCATION_2
  ON ALLOCATION (PROJNO);
```

Here I've defined the foreign key constraints as part of the column definition, but there's no reason other than convenience to do it this way; you could, if you chose, make them out-of-line constraints. Because the primary key consists of multiple columns you have to make it an out-of-line constraint as shown here.

I've also defined indexes on both of the foreign keys. This is important - delete performance from the parent tables will suffer if you don't do this.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can set combination key for  staffID CHAR (4) ,  projNo CHAR (4) for these two columns. and then add foreign key as usual.

```
CREATE TABLE [allocation](
    [staffID] [char](4) NOT NULL,
    [projNo] [char](4) NOT NULL,
    [hours] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_allocation] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [staffID] ASC,
    [projNo] ASC
))
```

Then set Foreign key with the help of alter command

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[allocation]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_allocation_project] FOREIGN KEY([projNo])
REFERENCES [dbo].[project] ([projNo])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[allocation] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_allocation_project]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[allocation]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_allocation_staff] FOREIGN KEY([staffID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[staff] ([staffID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[allocation] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_allocation_staff]
GO
```